# How to send whatsapp message Direct using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, whatsapp

I Have Implement it

On Page Load

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    debugger;
    $('#myButton').floatingWhatsApp({
        phone: '00000000',
        popupMessage: 'Hello, how can we help you?',
        message: "Testing",
        showPopup: true,
        showOnIE: false,
        headerTitle: 'Welcome!',
        headerColor: 'rgb(18, 140, 126)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(18, 140, 126)',
        buttonImage: '<img src="Whatsap/whatsapp.svg" />'
    });
});
```

LINK

> https://www.jqueryscript.net/social-media/Floating-WhatsApp-Message-Button-jQuery.html

Its Work Properly But the problem is, this is need for click on final submit button after scannig on whatsapp but i need to send web Messageto whatsapp on scanning only? is this possible????

Comment: That scan is used to authenticate the user with whatsapp. It does not trigger the function you intend.

Comment: No you have press the send button anyway.